# Forms fields respecting DRY django

Tags: django

Given some forms in Django (take the following for simplicity)

```
class LoginRegisterForm(forms.Form):

  email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", max_length=100)
  password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100)
```

We're trying to restrict the submission of these forms if there are additional fields submitted so we have the following added method to our form class

```
    def correct_fields(self):
      return set(self.data.keys()) == {"Email", "Password"}
```

And the following code in the `views.py` method corresponding to the submission of this form:

```
if form.is_valid() and form.correct_fields:
```

How can we avoid having to write `Email` and `Password` in both the definition of the form and the correct_fields method? Does django offer a build-in function to prevent forms being submitted if the correct fields are not submitted? (The form is still submitted if the correct fields and some additional fields are given). If this functionality is not given, how do I avoid writing the fields twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields where you do not specify `required=False` are *required*. As the documentation on the [**`required=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#required) says:

> By default, each `Field` class **assumes the value is required**, so if you pass an **empty value – either None or the empty string (`""`)** – then `clean()` will **raise a `ValidationError`** exception.

So it will already validate that `data` indeed contains `email` and `password`. You can define optional fields with:

```
class LoginRegisterForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(label="Email", max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(label="Password", widget=forms.PasswordInput(), max_length=100)
    info = forms.CharField(label="Tell us someting", required=False, intial='')
```

Comment: But my issue is what if data contains email, password and some other arbitrary fields? (at which point I would like to consider the form not valid)

Comment: @Bula: it will *not* be valid if the required fields are missing. All fields are by default required. Henced if `email` or `password` is missing here, `form.is_valid()` will return `False`. If `info` is missing, that is not a problem, since that was not required. In other words, a Django form *already* checks if the required fields are in the data.

Comment: My issue is `Email` , `Password` , `DontWantIt1` and `DontWantIt2` are also present and Django assumes this form is valid. I only want `Email` and `Password` without the added two fields

Comment: @Bula: but exactly what is the problem with extra data being shipped. In fact it is quite normal, since you can have for example *multiple* forms that each process part of the POST data. A formset is an example of that. In fact it would be against the DRY principle to eliminate that, since you create an extra dependency on apossible future form.

Comment: I see. I was not aware this is normal. I thought there might've been security concerns if additional fields are allowed